# Search engine for Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, lucene, search-engine, in-memory

What I'm trying to achieve is a way for quickly accessing in-memory data in a Laravel 5.7 app.

The data itself will be a structure obtained by processing some DB tables.

To this extent, from what I've searched and coming from the Java world, Lucene would offer me the features that I would need. However, I see that only Zend offer an integration lib with Lucene and it doesn't seem to have been updated since 5 years ago. I also found 2 wrappers over it (https://packagist.org/packages/nqxcode/laravel-lucene-search and https://github.com/nark3d/LaravelZendSearch), but both are incompatible with my setup, being targeted for older versions of Laravel. As such composer install fails for them.

I'm not hung up on Lucene at this point, any way of maintaining a searchable data structure in memory with decent performance would be good. However, I would not rely on external services, such as ElasticSearch or SOLR, as the setup in production does not currently include Java.

Does anyone know of alternatives that would be compatible with Laravel 5.7?

Comment: I would suggest you go through https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic has a good doc

Comment: Thanks, @bhucho, if I give up finding something that does not require additional processes started, the lib you suggested is certainly a good starting point :).